# how to stop posting of comment

Tags: php, wordpress

i m using Captcha on wp-comments form...my error message comes when captcha doen't match...but the problem is that on refreshing the page, i saw my comment posted there...how do i stop posting comment when captcha code is mismatches..m using 'comment_post' hook. Here is my code..

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'captcha_comment_post' );
function captcha_comment_post()
{
  if (isset($_POST["security_check"])) 
  {
    $code = str_decrypt($_POST["security_check"]);
    if (!( empty($code)) && !($code == $_POST['security_code'] ))
    {
        wp_die( 'Error, the Security Code does not match. Please Try Again.');
    }
   }
else {
    return ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When `$_POST["security_check"]` is not set, your check does not happen. Your script should only pass when the security code matches (don't check for fail, check for pass).

Also, I just did a bit of reading about Wordpress, but it seems that you may want to hook the comment before it posts using `pre_comment_on_post` rather than `comment_post`.

Comment: well when security code is not set, my error message comes but when i check after refreshing the page my comment is already posted there...i want to stop posting comment when security code mismatches..

Comment: with     pre_comment_on_post  hook my error message no display... i just tried     comment_text   filter hook... every thing works fine but now my text,which i m posting, not display...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of these solutions with no luck.  I finally just renamed the wp_comments table to wp_comments_none.